# AWS and Rackspace support

Tags: jelastic

I like what I see and hear from Jelastic. I was wondering if Jelastic will or does support AWS' ECS or Rackspace's Carina? I am just looking for bigger names in IaaS.

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if Jelastic will or does support AWS' ECS or Rackspace's Carina?

Yes. Jelastic can be installed on your own hardware, or on almost any public cloud infrastructure - but with the caveat that you get all of the limitations of that underlying infrastructure to go with it.

Naturally my opinion on this is somewhat biased, but having some insight into the workarounds and limitations necessary to apply Jelastic concepts onto AWS, Azure, Google Cloud means it's not something I would personally recommend anyone to do.

For example one of the clear gains from using Jelastic is the substantial cost saving because you do not pay for unused resources. If you layer Jelastic on top of 3rd party infrastructure, you have a fixed cost for that infrastructure => you are paying for unused resources again.

> I am just looking for bigger names in IaaS.

Jelastic recently published [a blog post](http://blog.jelastic.com/2016/12/14/aws-azure-google-cloud-and-jelastic-choose-your-cloud-hosting-by-location/) showing the very substantial size advantage of the [Jelastic Cloud Union](https://jelastic.cloud/) over what you think of as the dominant names.

In addition to having portability to migrate your workloads between different providers inside the Cloud Union, as you can see there are several providers offering multi-region directly too.

Overall you have many advantages by purchasing Jelastic service directly from an experienced and qualified provider, to give you the full benefits and capabilities of the platform - including better support and problem resolution since they have ownership of the full stack (relying on AWS or others infrastructure means you have an extra layer for finger pointing, misinformation, and delays when dealing with any issue).

Comment: Thanks Damien. I didn't realize Jelastic considers itself competition to the bigger IaaS hosters. From all the Jelastic providers, Layershift is also the most interesting to me currently. :-)